# updating array in object properties using properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object defined like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    lists: ["Dogs", "Cats"],
    items: {Dogs:[], Cats:[]}
    };
  }

  handleAddItem(item) {
    console.log(item);
  }
```

I have the variable

```
console.log(item);// output {Dogs:[{name: "lofi"}]}
```

I don't know how to verify which property is in the `item` (`Dogs` or `Cats`) so that I can update the object items{} to make it becоme in my example like this:

```
items{Dogs:[{name: "lofi"}], Cats:[]}
```

Comment: What do you mean with verify?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` method.

```
items[Object.keys(item)[0]] = item[Object.keys(item)[0]]
```

Working solution

```js
let state = {
   lists: ["Dogs", "Cats"],
   items: {Dogs:[], Cats:[]}
};

let item = { Dogs:[{name: "lofi"}] };
state.items[Object.keys(item)[0]] = item[Object.keys(item)[0]]
console.log(state.items);
```

Comment: I can't use '{ Dogs: [ {name: "lofi"} ] }' explicitly, I have to use the object 'item' and look for the same property in 'items' to update

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign` function on the `state.items`, which will add/update the given object with the properties given at the second parameter.

```js
let state = {
   lists: ["Dogs", "Cats"],
   items: { Dogs:[], Cats:[] }
};

let item = { Dogs: [ {name: "lofi"} ] };

Object.assign(state.items, item);

console.log(state);
```

Comment: I can't use '{ Dogs: [ {name: "lofi"} ] }' explicitly, I have to use the object 'item' and look for the same property  in 'items' to update.

Comment: Will your `item` contain either `Dogs` or `Cats`?

Comment: yes, both `Dogs` or `Cats` or even other animals that I can add

Comment: You don't need to know what is in the `item`, it just gets the properties from that and put them into the `state.items`